# Not getting message from resource bundle

Tags: java, spring, internationalization

I have configured the Spring configuration xml to use the "ResourceBundleMessageSource" and I am trying to get the message from the resource bundle file but while I am to to execute I get the log on that says : it could not find the resource bundle with given name.

More prcisely :

```
WARN org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource - ResourceBundle [messages] not found for MessageSource: Can't find bundle for base name messages, locale en_US
```

My configuration of spring.xml

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename">
        <value>messages</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The way in which I am trying to use in my code :

```
ResourceBundleMessageSource rbms = (ResourceBundleMessageSource) applicationCtx.getBean("messageSource");
String message = rbms.getMessage("key001", parameters,"default message", null);
```

And part of my messages.properties (I have put this file under project/src/)

```
key001 = Problem occurred while fetching the results from database. Please see log.
```

I tried renaming the file with messages_en_US.properites also but it didn't help.

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The properties file needs to be in classpath of the application when it is running; is your IDE/Compiler (and/or ant/maven build process) copying *.properties to the "output" path?

If not, it needs to. (Try copying it manually to begin with)